# onItemClickListener is not getting fired

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

onItemClcikListener is not getting fired with reference to a list view.

This is my row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView" >
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textColor="#000"
                            android:text="BioMass Pellets"
                            android:id="@+id/productName" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my main.xml

```
<LinearLayout>
     <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Within onCreateView method I have returned the rootview after setting the adapter. Im trying to setOnItemClickListener for listview as follows,

```
mListView = (ListView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + position + " is the position you clicked!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     } });
```

Comment: could you perhaps try `setDecentantFocusability` to `FOCUS_AFTER_CHILDREN` on either the linearlayout or the listview itself.

Comment: add the attribute for blocking descendants to Your row parent LinearLayout: android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"...if You have views inside that consume the click event, itemOnClickListener wont work......

Comment: no bro..it is not working

Comment: you added  android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false" in each view of your  row.xml..

Comment: i tried that as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.
 
Use listview.setOnClickListener() in you activity class containing Listview.it will work Perfectly fine As looking into your code it seems you are using it in Adapter class

Comment: sure let me try that out

Comment: still the same problem persists

Comment: @Stanly i figured out now u are using ScrollView and listview, where as listview has default scroll they are conflicting each other. try by cancelling the scroll of listview.

Comment: @Stanly did u got what i am saying?

Comment: when i click it, it appears like clicking but onClick method is not getting fired. Should I add 'focusable' to `false` at listview

Comment: @Stanly Yeah now try adding all xml properties

Answer (score 0):

In your LinearLayout or parent layout of list_item use `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`.
your item class should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:orientation="vertical">
```

Comment: should I set that to linearlayout of main.xml or row.xml?

Comment: Set it into your row xml @Stanly

Comment: sure i will set that

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to add  `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants".` to root layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

also
Just put

```
 android:focusable="false"
 android:clickable="false"
```

in the row/item.xml of the listView .